# SKScene loading without contents and appropriate background color

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have this code to switch from one SKScene to the other:

```
let nextScene = MenuScene(size: self.scene!.size)
let transition = SKTransition.revealWithDirection(.Down, duration: 1.0)
scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

self.scene?.view?.presentScene(nextScene, transition: transition)
```

The new scene renders in a different background color than was specified in .sks and no nodes are visible. Sorry for the small amount of code, which i fear will not give much insight into my problem.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hamobi does have the correct answer, but this approach might be easier, and does not require an extension.

```
let nextScene = MenuScene(fileNamed:"MenuScene")
nextScene.size = self.scene!.size
let transition = SKTransition.revealWithDirection(.Down, duration: 1.0)
nextScene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

self.scene?.view?.presentScene(nextScene, transition: transition)
```

Note,  moving from scene to scene like this is bad design, the scene should be telling the view that a transition is happening,  and the view should be doing the presenting outside of the scene object,  so that the old scene can properly deallocate

Comment: It solves the problem! This design where the scene tells the view sounds interesting. How would I go about setting up such a design?

Comment: the way I do it is through delegation,  if you look up how to delegate view controllers,  you will see a plethora of tutorials on this.  you basically take the same concept, and apply it to view and scene

Comment: basically what goes on is the scene says "My purpose is done". Then the view can be notified it is done, and will handle what to do next.  Now the view knows when a scene is completed, and could do things like stop timers that it may have running,  without having complicated code.

Answer (score 2):

if youre creating it from an sks file then you need to instantiate the scene using your sks file.  Check this out.. might help

[Unarchiving .sks file in Swift for iOS 7.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30082825/unarchiving-sks-file-in-swift-for-ios-7-1)